# Minimum required time to bind a tcp and udp socket after pc interface change

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am a C++ developer and develop a C++ application. My application run very nice. But when i change my pc interface then my application can not bind TCP socket for a few moments. So i need to know how much time we need to wait to bind a TCP socket after pc interface change.

Comment: Why? If it's a server just bind it to INADDR_ANY. If it's a client, don't bind it at all: TCP will do it for you when you connect.

Comment: Firstly, it is a client. If we use INADDR_ANY then no fail to bind but when we set a select a interface then bind fail. But after some time same interface can successfully bind.

Comment: As it is a client, you have no apparent requirement to bind at all, as I said above. If you do bind, you certainly can't use INADDR_ANY. That's for servers.